# ArrayList of abstract subclasses (must have different hashcode)

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract

I am creating a game for a school project, and I have a 2 classes called Pieces and Powers, with subclasses Piece_Yellow, Piece_Blue ... and Power_Explode, Power_ChangeColor etc...

I was doing it with enum and someone from this website (mikera to be more precise) help me changing that and creating a better interaction with the pieces and the powers.

But now I have to change the old code, and I have problems with that because I was doing like this :

```
int x = 10, y = 5;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (pecas[x][y] == null)
        pecas[x][y] = new Piece(arrayPecas.get(rand.nextInt(arrayPecas.size())));
}
```

Like this my array was partially filled with 10 new pieces Objects with different colors (but no powers, that was the problem), and every single one had a different hashcode (for finding , comparing and deleting the pieces later)...

But Since we can't initiliaze an abstract class, the only solution that I've found to this problem was to do this :

```
int x = 10, y = 5;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (pecas[x][y] == null)
        pecas[x][y] = arrayPecas.get(rand.nextInt(arrayPecas.size()));
}
```

Like this the object is still added, but now I have 1 problems :
1 - All the hashcode from the pieces with the same color are the same... I don't really know how to solve this. I've read that I could override the hashcode method but there is no information to make the difference between them (and I can't store the position because I had to change it every time the piece change position).

Comment: I don't know where you are using the hashcode, but at first, why it is a problem that they have the same hashcode? As long as equals is different, because they represent different objects.

Comment: because of the arraylist. When I have a sequence (3 in a row) the pieces in that sequence are sended to a temporary arraylist, and that array list passes by a hashset (to remove the similar pieces, since we can have 6 pieces horizontal and vertical with 1 piece already used that can't be counted 2 times), and because of that the hashset removes all and keep only 1 of each

Comment: I think you should instantiate using the subclasses instead of Piece. Assuming the subclasses extend Piece class.

Comment: @Vincent Like that I had to instantiate for each piece, and if someday I had new pieces or new powers I had to change that parte of the code again no ? (That is what I was trying to prevent :S)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that really the hashCodes that are your problem.  It's that the objects are simply equal.  Code that relies on two unequal objects having different hashCodes isn't strictly correct.  `return 1;` is a perfectly legal implementation of `Object#hashCode()`.

The simplest thing seems to be to put a clone() method on Piece that all the subclasses can implement in order to return copies in places where you want different, distinct, objects.

```
public abstract class Piece {

  public abstract Piece clonePiece();

}

public class YellowPiece extends Piece {

  @Override
  public Piece clonePiece() {
    return new YellowPiece(this.relevantThing1, this.relevantThing2 // etc etc)
  }
}

int x = 10, y = 5;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (pecas[x][y] == null)
        pecas[x][y] = arrayPecas.get(rand.nextInt(arrayPecas.size())).clonePiece();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just one question, what if the relevantThing is the same for all ? Because What I have is an array of objects that contain all the information inside of their own class plus the power associated with them, and they have to be diferent.. Will this work in this case ?

Comment: Then you have to add `clonePiece()` into `Power` object as well. Each of the subclasses will have their own relevant thing to do in the `clonePiece()` method.

Comment: But what would made the diferent between 2 yellow pieces with the same power ?

Comment: This will result in the same behaviour you'd expect to get if `new Piece(arrayPecas.get(rand.nextInt(arrayPecas.size())))` were legal.  If that isn't enough, probably need to see more of what you're actually doing with these things.  But yes, any properties of Piece that are mutable, you will need to also make clones of to set on the new Piece.  I don't think using an enum would have prevented this.

Comment: I will try like this and see If I can make the thing work. Thanks again !